# Unable to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft and .NET'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, signalr, nuget

Not much I can say about this, just installed VS 2015 Community, trying to install SignalR and this error pops out.

[image]

Comment: Can you (re-)type the error, so that e.g. search machines will pick it up? Also it might make sense to include the error message in the actual question title.

Comment: The error is "Unable to resolve dependency Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb"